CUDA Out of Memory Error Despite Having Multiple GPUs
I'm encountering a CUDA out-of-memory error while trying to run a PyTorch model, even though my system has multiple NVIDIA GPUs.
# Load the tokenizer and model
tokenizer = AutoTokenizer.from_pretrained("MODEL_TYPE")
model = AutoModelForCausalLM.from_pretrained("MODEL_TYPE", output_attentions=True, device_map = 'auto', torch_dtype=torch.float16, low_cpu_mem_usage=True)

I have 8 GPU's and the model is distributed across all of them. However since my input is long context (about 20k token). I get a CUDA memory error for GPU0 despite having lots of space in other GPUS. Note this is an inference on batch size 1.
OutOfMemoryError: CUDA out of memory. Tried to allocate 20.11 GiB. GPU 0 has a total capacty of 22.17 GiB of which 16.06 GiB is free. Including non-PyTorch memory, this process has 6.10 GiB memory in use. Of the allocated memory 5.57 GiB is allocated by PyTorch, and 308.62 MiB is reserved by PyTorch but unallocated. If reserved but unallocated memory is large try setting max_split_size_mb to avoid fragmentation.  See documentation for Memory Management and PYTORCH_CUDA_ALLOC_CONF

inputs = tokenizer(prompt, return_tensors="pt")
torch.cuda.empty_cache()
model.generation_config.temperature = temp
model.eval()
with torch.no_grad():
    output = model.generate(inputs.input_ids, max_length=25000, output_attentions=False,output_scores=False, return_dict_in_generate=True)
    print("temp:",model.generation_config.temperature)
tokens = tokenizer.convert_ids_to_tokens(inputs['input_ids'][0])


response = tokenizer.batch_decode(output[0], skip_special_tokens=False, clean_up_tokenization_spaces=False)[0]

How can I efficiently utilize the available GPUs for the long context inputs to avoid the out-of-memory error?
I tried forcing the inputs to other GPUs but that didn't work:
inputs = tokenizer(prompt, return_tensors="pt").to("cuda:1")


Have you had a look at the page on how to efficiently train on multiple gpus? There is also a memory calculator.
